# VueJS with Nuxtjs Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm relatively new to VueJS, and I'm wondering what is happening here. Below is my code from following this tutorial on [Server Side Rendering with Nuxtjs Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUWsjUxxUQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkbvTj8AUUCfBO7DoEHJ-ME&index=9). But it outputs the following error when I did `firebase serve`. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong here?

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="fact in facts" :key="fact.text">
      {{ fact.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
    import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

    export default {
      async asyncData() {
        const response = await fetch('https://nuxt-ssr.firebaseio.com/facts.json');
        const facts = await response.json();
        return facts;
      }
    }
</script>
```

> error: [Vue warn]: Property or method "facts" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this prop erty
>   is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components,
>   by initializing the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of asyncData method your facts is an array. In asyncData ( like in normal vue data function) you need to return dictionary.

So it should be as following:

```
export default {
  async asyncData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://nuxt-ssr.firebaseio.com/facts.json');
    const facts = await response.json();
    return {facts}; // Same as return  { facts: facts }
  }
}
```